# Catkin Workspace is not on the current folder

Tags: workspace, catkin

I am trying to initialize a catkin workspace: create a folder and inside it I created /src then $catkin init, but then the workspace path is shown somewhere else:

**ABC:~ xxl$ cd spoc_lite_ws/**

**ABC:spoc_lite_ws xxl$ catkin config**

---

Profile:                     default

Extending:        [explicit] /opt/ros/lunar

Workspace:                   /Users/xlei

---

Source Space:      [missing] /Users/xxl/src

Log Space:         [missing] /Users/xxl/logs

Build Space:       [missing] /Users/xxl/build

Devel Space:       [missing] /Users/xxl/devel

Install Space:      [unused] /Users/xxl/nstall

DESTDIR:            [unused] None

---

Devel Space Layout:          linked

Install Space Layout:        None

---

Additional CMake Args:       None

Additional Make Args:        None

Additional catkin Make Args: None

Internal Make Job Server:    True

Cache Job Environments:      False

---

Whitelisted Packages:        None

Blacklisted Packages:        None

---

---

WARNING: Source space `/Users/xxl/src` does

not yet exist.

---

**ABC:spoc_lite_ws xxl$ ls**

src

---

How can I change the working workspace to be *spoc_lite_ws*?
Thanks and happy new year!

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem after moving the workspace to another directory. In my case, I solved the problem by removing the directory `.catkin_tools/`. I guess that the old cache of `.catkin_tools/` remained.

Reference: https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_init.html